# Unique Properties of the Euclidean Norm

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

**Preamble**
A friend and I enjoy passing the time by picking arbitrary favorites in mathematics. Recently we have been talking about our favorite distance metrics. Being an engineer by training, the Euclidean norm is close to my heart. Him, being a geometric group theorist, thinks that the euclidean norm is overrated. He favors the p-adic norm, or your common or garden taxicab metric.

**Question**
Does the euclidean norm possess any mathematical properties which are unique to it among metrics. Or are at least rare properties for a metric to possess. Features which make it in some way distinct as a norm.

**Supplementary**
If you have any personal favorite norms or recommendations for further reading I would appreciate hearing them.

Comment: There is a paper ([link](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258222305_What%27s_so_special_about_Euclidean_distance_A_characterization_with_applications_to_mobility_and_spatial_voting)) about this in the context of economics. I don't find the authors' characterization of Euclidean distance very intuitive, but it's there. If you can come up with an intuitive explanation, let me know!

Comment: "The Euclidean norm is overrated" :-)

Comment: Euclidean norm is indeed overrated, but why [$p$-adic norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_order#p-adic_absolute_value) unless you are doing $p$-adic analysis on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ or similar?

Answer (score 1):

The generalization of the Euclidean norm to function spaces is the $L_2$ norm. Of all the $L_p$ spaces, only $L_2$ is a Hilbert space. [I leave it to the reader to track down the definitions of $L_p$ norm and of Hilbert space to see why this is a big deal.]

Comment: I agree. [I recommend having a look at this recent discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4054831/8157), where all elements of this "big deal" appear. The keyword is "orthogonality".